# How to set rowcount? JTable setRowCount GUI by Jtextfield and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I tried to create a table and manipulate it.
but I do not understand what code should I write in my netbeans.

JTextField1 variable n
JButton1 Variable ok
JTable1 Variable tabel1

on JButton1 or Ok Button I give code like this:

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int key = Integer.parseInt(n.getText());
    c.setText(String.valueOf(key));
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabel1.getModel();
    for(int i = 0; i < key; i++){
    int r = tabel1.getRowCount()+1;
    dtm.setRowCount(r);
    }

}
```

with code that I write, I managed to make the line corresponds to the number on JTextField1.

but when i press the ok button continuously. rows in the table continues to grow.

how can i make that row in the table according to Jtextfield1 and no longer grow?

thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabel1.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(rowcount); // instead you can use your textfiled value here
e.g. dtm.setRowCount(Integer.parseInt((txtFieldName.getText()));
    tabel1.setModel(dtm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int key = Integer.parseInt(n.getText());
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabel1.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < key; i++){
    int r = tabel1.getRowCount()+1;
    dtm.setRowCount(r);
    }        
}
```